# Copying an existing Magento site to run locally

Tags: magento, xampp

I am having a hard time running my Magento site website locally using xampp. I have downloaded everything in the public_html to the htdocs folder. It is giving me a n error when i load

> SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'mySite_magstore'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

I loaded up the phpmyadmin panel to check the password but it is not loading the one from my website but the new one i have locally. I'm sure I am missing a step here as well.

All the information I have found online is regarding setting up a new site on xampp but could not find anything about using an existing one. Any help or links would help.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you created the mysql user mySite_magstore locally?

Comment: I just did but it is still throwing the same error. I guess its because i do not have any of  the database information from the live site. That may be the fundamental issue I am having.

Comment: I would suggest that you just delete app/etc/local.xml and install your Magento on the local machine. during the installation process specify the database that you've copied from your live environment

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you want to create a test environment in your machine, try the following steps:

Export your  live DB

Import it in your local machine

Go in to the core_config_data table and change the 'value' of:

```
 web/unsecure/base_url
```

And:

```
web/secure/base_url
```

To:

```
http://127.0.0.1/
```

Go in to:

```
app/etc/local.xml
```

And change the username and password to the correct ones

**Edit:**

Thanks to [Cooper Maruyana](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1159949/cooper-maruyama) for bringining this up:

If the previous step doesn't help delete *everything* in the 'var' folder.

Comment: `web/unsecure/base_url` and `web/secure/base_url` left me scratching my head for hours when I first started with Magento.  Why is my local copy redirecting to the main site?!?

Comment: when i started i had the same problem, magento looks in to the db to know where to pull the template code (allowing you to have a dedicated db server)

Comment: If you find your local magento is still redirecting even after changing the `base_url` values in the db, you need to delete *everything* inside the `var` folder in the magento root. @pzirkind if you can append this to your answer that would be great.

Answer (score 2):

Check your `app\etc\local.xml` for below line

```
<password><![CDATA[]]></password>
```

I am sure you have set some password for production server, but on your local you don't have any password for your root user. So you need to remove that password and also set you base URL in core_config table.

Answer (score 1):

There are two possible options: one is to copy your database from your server to your localhost as pzirkind has illustrated in his answer.
The second option in case you want to use exactly the same database, i.e. you WANT to use your live database:
You need to adjust your app/etc/local.xml file to point to the database server IP address. Currently there should be "localhost" in there. Remove that and put the database server IP address. If you have setup the user on the database to allow remote access (% for scope in phpmyadmin), then this would work, too.
However, I would not recommend this option. I only use it sometimes to share a database between development and staging areas, but never for live sites.
Therefore, I would highly recommend pzirkind's approach!